# How to make this loop repeat until right value has been added, Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to get the below code to repeat until one of the correct string values is entered.

```
while True:
    if value in ['man united', 'man city', 'liverpool', 'chelsea']:
        print(tabulate(data[value]))
        break
    if value not in ['man united', 'man city', 'liverpool', 'chelsea']:
        print("You entered a wrong option, Please enter a correct option")
        print(f"1: {options}")
```

I've tried a couple different ways but can't achieve exactly what I'm looking for.
This code is within a python function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
New to Python

Comment: not sure what result you expect exactly. Additionally the second 'if value not in' seems not needed. You checked the condition in the first 'if' and if True you break. Then if not True you do the rest without needing to check the condition again

Comment: Where do you get `value` ?

Comment: As presented, the code should properly break out of the `while True` loop once the condition is met. What exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I think you could do it, l is just a list containing the options, but you do not have to use it.

```
l = ['man united', 'man city', 'liverpool', 'chelsea']
value = input()

while value not in l:
    print("You entered a wrong option, Please enter a correct option")
    print(f"1: {options}")
    value = input() #or however you want to change the value variable

print(tabulate(data[value])) #this will execute only once the correct choice has been selcted
```

Comment: Absolute hero. Thanks so much. Was able to edit slightly as my "values" were coming from a dictionary laid out about but that seems to have solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!